# Returning multiple View objects from a closure in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, closures

I often see code like this:

```
VStack {
  Text("A")
  Text("B")
}
```

From looking at the swift tutorials, I know that this is shorthand for specifying a closure as the last parameter to a function. However, afaik if the `return` keyword is not specified, a closure will implicitly return the result of the expression inside.

In this case, there are two `Text` objects. Are they returned as a tuple or a list? I know it works, but its unclear to me, what exactly is being returned from the closure.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The initial ability to omit the return statement was introduced in [Swift Evolution 255](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0255-omit-return.md) - This change only allowed for a single return value.  In fact, the ability to return multiple values was considered in this proposal and discarded.

The structure you are asking about was originally introduced by Apple as a private implementation to support SwiftUI but has now been officially adopted in [Swift Evolution 289 - Function Builders](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0289-function-builders.md).

By referring to the [introduction](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0289-function-builders.md#introduction) section of that document you can see that the values are, indeed, returned as a tuple.

```
// Original source code:
@TupleBuilder
func build() -> (Int, Int, Int) {
  1
  2
  3
}

// This code is interpreted exactly as if it were this code:
func build() -> (Int, Int, Int) {
  let _a = TupleBuilder.buildExpression(1)
  let _b = TupleBuilder.buildExpression(2)
  let _c = TupleBuilder.buildExpression(3)
  return TupleBuilder.buildBlock(_a, _b, _c)
}
```

Comment: It still amazes me how powerful a language Swift really is. Thanks for this answer, it clears up all my questions.

Comment: @BenjaminTamasi its not powerful, its a convoluted mess.

Answer (score 1):

When we see this code:

```
VStack {
  Text("A")
  Text("B")
}
```

It is unclear what would be returned, unless we use `VStack`, then SwiftUI knows what we want, the code could be like this:

```
HStack {
  Text("A")
  Text("B")
}
```

Here also is unclear what we want, unless we say to SwiftUI that we want `HStack`, But if you use like this:

```
CustomView {
  Text("A")
  Text("B")
}
```

SwiftUI return it as `VStack` the inside content always! Also in all those cases that I said, Swift works with `@ViewBuilder` to make that happen. and they are tuple.

[ViewBuilder Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/viewbuilder)

Answer (score 1):

SwiftUI automatically returns the two Text’s in a type of TupleView. Swift’s resultBuilder is the magic, which was SE0289: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0289-result-builders.md

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I wanted :)